# Add rows to the beginning of a tableview without animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add rows to a tableview with begin/endUpdates to prevent the jump of the tableview when i do reloadData

this is my code

```
- (void)updateTableWithNewRowCount:(NSInteger)rowCount
                        andNewData:(NSArray *)newData {
  // Save the tableview content offset
  CGPoint tableViewOffset = [self.messagesTableView contentOffset];

  // Turn of animations for the update block
  // to get the effect of adding rows on top of TableView
  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

  [self.messagesTableView beginUpdates];

  NSMutableArray *rowsInsertIndexPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  int heightForNewRows = 0;

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [rowsInsertIndexPath addObject:tempIndexPath];
//    [self.messages insertObject:[newData objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];
      [self addMessage:[newData objectAtIndex:i]];

    heightForNewRows =
        heightForNewRows + [self heightForCellAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
  }

  [self.messagesTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsInsertIndexPath
                                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

  tableViewOffset.y += heightForNewRows;

  [self.messagesTableView endUpdates];

  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

  [self.messagesTableView setContentOffset:tableViewOffset animated:NO];
}
```

And sometimes (not everytime) I get this error

```
 invalid number of rows in section 0.
 The number of rows contained in an existing section after
 the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
 before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
 from that section (2 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
 rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved  out).
```

How do i prevent this error ?

Comment: Are you updating your dataSource array as well with the new data, before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method

Comment: yes I am - this row does it   [self addMessage:[newData objectAtIndex:i]];

Comment: Try putting breakpoint in numberOfRows, cellForRowAtIndexPath method and in addMessage method, and check whether your new object is getting added before UITableView is getting reloaded.

Comment: the problem is, it doesnt happen on my device - only on a remote device, and according to the message, the number of rows before update is 2 and the numbere of rows after update is also 2, and 2 rows were inserted, so i should have 4 rows ? or 2 rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to quickly jump to a selected indexPath (with or without animation), you can use this function:

```
//My function to populate
//tableView is synthesized
-(void)setNewMessage:(NSString*)message{
    // ...
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    // if your selectedIndexPath==nil, the table scroll stay in the same position
    [self reloadData:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];
}

//My reload data wrapper
-(void)reloadData:(NSIndexPath *)selectedIndexPath animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [tableView reloadData];
    // atScrollPosition can receive different parameters (eg:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle) 
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                             animated:animated];
}
```

Once I needed that same flexibility in a tableView and this function has met my needs. You don`t need the "setAnimationsEnabled", just use:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nil
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                         animated:NO];
];
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: since my cells are not selectable, i used "visible cells" method instead of "selected cell"

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want animation then use directly

```
- (void)updateTableWithNewRowCount:(NSInteger)rowCount
                        andNewData:(NSArray *)newData {
  // Save the tableview content offset
  CGPoint tableViewOffset = [self.messagesTableView contentOffset];

  // Turn of animations for the update block
  // to get the effect of adding rows on top of TableView

  NSMutableArray *rowsInsertIndexPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  int heightForNewRows = 0;

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [rowsInsertIndexPath addObject:tempIndexPath];
//    [self.messages insertObject:[newData objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];
      [self addMessage:[newData objectAtIndex:i]];

    heightForNewRows =
        heightForNewRows + [self heightForCellAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
  }

  tableViewOffset.y += heightForNewRows;

  [self.messagesTableView reloadData];

  [self.messagesTableView setContentOffset:tableViewOffset animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: in this case the table jumps to the end - and i want it to stay where it is - notice i am adding the given rows at the beginning of the table, not the end of it

Comment: Hey @LenaBru my answer is helpful to you or not?

Comment: @PradipVanparia I dont know yet, i'll be able to put it in the app only in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure whether this will work or not.

```
- (void)updateTableWithNewRowCount:(NSInteger)rowCount
                        andNewData:(NSArray *)newData {
  // Save the tableview content offset
  CGPoint tableViewOffset = [self.messagesTableView contentOffset];

  // Turn of animations for the update block
  // to get the effect of adding rows on top of TableView
  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

  NSMutableArray *rowsInsertIndexPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  int heightForNewRows = 0;

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

    NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [rowsInsertIndexPath addObject:tempIndexPath];
//    [self.messages insertObject:[newData objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i];
      [self addMessage:[newData objectAtIndex:i]];

    heightForNewRows = heightForNewRows + [self heightForCellAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
  }

  tableViewOffset.y += heightForNewRows;
  [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

  [self.messagesTableView setContentOffset:tableViewOffset animated:NO];

  double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
  dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
  dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

     [self.messagesTableView beginUpdates];
     [self.messagesTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsInsertIndexPath
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
     [self.messagesTableView endUpdates];
  });
}
```

**Note:** You might require to update `rowsInsertIndexPath` reference to use inside the block (`__block` type).